# Another issue with prolog

Tags: prolog

Im not sure why my husband function is giving me a false, the logic should be right. It gives a correct answer when I remove male(X) and female(Y). Everything else returns the proper answer. I am fairly new with this language. Here is the code:

```
male(bob).
male(brody).
male(aaron).
male(daniel).
male(adam).
male(james).
male(jerry).

female(judy).
female(melinda).
female(erin).
female(lena).
female(cristin).

father(bob,lena).
father(bob,jeff).
father(james,adam).
father(jerry,cristin).
father(adam,brody).
father(adam,aaron).
father(jeff,daniel).

mother(judy,lena).
mother(judy,jeff).
mother(erin,adam).
mother(melinda,cristin).
mother(lena,brody).
mother(lena,aaron).
mother(cristin,daniel).

parent(X, Y) :- father(X, Y); mother(X, Y).                   
children(X,Y):-parent(Y,X).                  
grandfather(X, Y) :- father(X, Z), parent(Z, Y). 
grandmother(X, Y) :- mother(X, Z), parent(Z, Y).
sibling(X,Y):-
  parent(Z,X),
  parent(Z,Y),
  X\=Y.

sister(X,Y):-
  sibling(X,Y),
  female(X).


brother(X,Y):-
  sibling(X,Y),
  male(X).




husband(X,Y):-
  male(X),
  female(Y),
  children(M,X),
  children(M,Y).
```

Comment: What Prolog implementation do you use? It works for me with gprolog.

Comment: I am using swi for my implementation and the code is written in sublime

Comment: If you don't use the male/female predicates, what solutions do you get from husband? (Of course some where a female is the father, and some where X=Y, but the wanted ones should be included too.)

Comment: Now I tried SWI Prolog too, and I get solutions, starting with bob and judy.

Comment: When I don't use the male/female predicates it would return the husband and when you press tab or ; it gives the wife as well. The optimal solution is just return husband when you do husband(X, wife).

Comment: `husband(X,Y).` shows me both X and Y at the same time, on separate lines. I run it in an ordinary terminal window.

Comment: That's pretty weird, I'm not sure why mine just shows false. Especially when I try to do husband(X, cristin).